# Example of Stablizer of element which isn't normal

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

There is a nice theorem, that states that for $G$ acting on $G$ (as group action on set) by product from the left- i.e for every $g_1,g_2 \in G, g_1\cdot g_2:=g_1g_2$; a stabilizer of $ s \in G$ , (which I'll notate by $G_s$ ), is normal if and only if it stabilise every element of $Gs$- as product of $s$ with the set from the left, pointwise.

I'm trying to come up with example that it is not always right: a group acts on set with not normal stabilizer for some element.

Can someone give some exapmle?

Comment: A stabilizer in the natural action of $S_3$ on $\{1,2,3\}$. In fact all subgroups $H$ of all groups $G$ arise as stabilizers in the action of $G$ by left multiplication on the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: The first paragraph of the question, though true, suggests that you don't fully understand stabilizers. When $G$ acts on itself by multiplication from the left, all the stabilizers $G_s$ are just the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$.

Comment: These should be so abundant you would have stumbled upon one if you looked! Indeed, orbit-stabilizer (if you're familiar with it) says any transitive action is equivalent to a coset space $G/H$, in which all the stabilizers are conjugates of $H$, which are nonnormal iff $H$ is not normal. So you can literally pick any nonnormal subgroup $H< G$ and consider the action $G\curvearrowright G/H$.

Comment: @runway44 This seems to be a common problem with group theory questions on this site. In particular, questions asking for an example that obviously needs to be nonabelian are often answerable by the smallest nonabelian group $S_3$ (and if that doesn't work, then the nonabelian groups of order $8$ have a good chance).

Comment: Thanks guys. It is helpful :)